# Stripe signature not found: Express Middleware Question

Tags: node.js, express, stripe-payments, webhooks, middleware

I am new to full stack development. I am having an issue with using a webhook for the first time, specifically one from a stripe checkout session. From my understanding, stripe requires the raw body of the request to properly decode the signature. My backend uses a few middlewares that I believe are getting in the way of the raw body parser from doing it's job. I understand that I need to apply a form of if/else to allow my backend to decide which middleware/s to use, but I am unsure of how to properly do it. Here is my code:

```
// only use the raw bodyParser for webhooks
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    if (req.originalUrl === '/webhook') {
        next();
    } else {
        cors();
        express.json({limit: '50mb'})
        express.urlencoded({limit: '50mb', extended: true})
    }
});

//app.use(cors());
//app.use(express.json({limit: '50mb'}));
//app.use(express.urlencoded({limit: '50mb', extended: true}));
```

The commented out app.use statements are my middlewares that were properly working before I attempted to get my webhook working. This code does not work, it is just my attempt to apply the middlewares properly. The following is my post route for the webhook, which is just a copied version of the docs from stripe, which I will edit once I successfully receive the webhook:

```
// Stripe requires the raw body to construct the event
app.post('/webhook', bodyParser.raw({type: 'application/json'}), (req, res) => {
    const sig = req.headers['stripe-signature'];
    
  
    let event;
  
    try {
      event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(req.body, sig, webhookSecret);
    } catch (err) {
      // On error, log and return the error message
      console.log(`❌ Error message: ${err.message}`);
      return res.status(400).send(`Webhook Error: ${err.message}`);
    }
  
    // Successfully constructed event
    console.log('✅ Success:', event.id);
  
    // Return a response to acknowledge receipt of the event
    res.json({received: true});
});
```

Error Message: No signatures found matching the expected signature for payload. Are you passing the raw request body you received from Stripe? https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node#webhook-signing

Answer (score 1):

It appears that after hours of messing around, I solved my own question just minutes after finally deciding to post it here! But of course....lol

My solution that worked:

```
// only use the raw bodyParser for webhooks
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    if (req.originalUrl === '/webhook') {
        next();
    } else { 
        express.json({limit: '50mb'})(req, res, next);
    }
});

app.use(cors());
//app.use(express.json({limit: '50mb'}));
app.use(express.urlencoded({limit: '50mb', extended: true}));
```